# Drawing data 1 by 1 D3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to draw the data points 1 by 1. Since its 22.000 some data points I want them to be drawn AFTER each other not all at the same time.

Any suggestions how to do it? I cant seem to figure it out.

ps. the code for running through all the data is not there obviously because I dont know how.

```
// add the tooltip area to the webpage
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);


// load data
d3.csv("giants.csv", function(error, data) {

  // draw dots
     svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle" )
      .attr("class",  function(d) {
            var c = " ";
                    c="dot " + d["last"];

          return c;
        })
      .attr("r", 1.5)
      .attr("cx", xMap)
      .attr("cy", yMap)

      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(cValue(d));}) 
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {


          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(500)


               .style("opacity", .9);
          tooltip.html("<img class='playerfoto' src=img/"+d["last"]+".png><img class='playerfoto'src='img/sf.png'><br/>" +" "+ d["last"]+", "+ d["first"]+ "<br/><br/>" +"Pitch made on: "+d["date"]+"<br/> "+"Batter faced : " + d["batter_last"] +", "+ d["batter_first"]+
              "<br/> (" + xValue(d)+ ", " + yValue(d) + ")")


               .style("left", (  20) + "px")
               .style("top", (  20) + "px");

      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(500)
               .style("opacity", 0);
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding the answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206948/d3-progressively-draw-a-large-dataset):

> I think you'll have to chunk your data and display it in groups using setInterval or setTimeout. This will give the UI some breathing room to jump in the middle.
>
> The basic approach is: 1) chunk the data set 2) render each chunk separately 3) keep track of each rendered group

You could use the Javascript [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) function to call your update code at various time intervals, and change the update to plot only a single row of the data (or 100 rows chuncks for example)
For a single element:

```
svg.append("circle").datum(dataset[currentIndex])
      .attr( //...all the other stuff, unchanged
```

Changing it this way just adds a circle with `dataset[currentIndex]` as it's datum, without computing any join between selection and data.

[Here is a small example JSFiddle I've created as a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/83joe0mt/5/)

Note that `setInterval` is limited to 4ms as minimum interval (and even more on some browsers), so drawing thousands of elements one by one will take a lot of time as you are limited to 250 elements/second. What you can do is draw "chunks" at every iteration, like 20 elements per iteration. This way you can draw 1000/interval*chunksize elements/second, for example with interval=20 and chunksize=20, 1000 elements/second. If you tune right the two parameters (interval and chunksize) nobody will be able to distinguish between element by element or chunk by chunk

[Here is a JSFiddle that draws by chunks](http://jsfiddle.net/83joe0mt/7/)

Comment: Thanks @LeartS. just encounterd 1 problem though. The minimum interval.. takes ages before all the points are drawn on the svg now